# Jenkins can't connect to github repo

Tags: linux, jenkins, github

I have ubuntu 20.04 LTS
I'm trying to connect my local jenkins to github repo, where is my Jenkinsfile but I'm always getting this error:

***Failed to connect to repository : Command "/usr/bin/git ls-remote -h -- https://github.com/RaulMartinezL/almacen_infinito HEAD" returned status code 128:
stdout:
stderr: remote: Invalid username or password.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/RaulMartinezL/almacen_infinito/'***

I don't know what is going on because I have exactly the same path '/usr/bin/git' setup on PyCharm and it does work for cloning repositories. In fact, it is the same repository.

Then I check on terminal the path, and I get this:
***bash: cd: usr/bin/git: Not a directory***

I have checked this commands too:

which git:
***/usr/bin/git***
type git:
***git is hashed (/usr/bin/git)***

I don't know what is wrong and why the path works on PyCharm and not on Jenkins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the error states  username / password error.

```
cd: usr/bin/git: Not a directory
```

correct! because git is executable, not directory.

check your username and password.

---

To add a credential, click on “Add” next to “Credentials” -> Select “Jenkins Credential Provider”, this will display the following add credentials screen.

[image]

[Reference for further information](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2016/10/jenkins-git-setup/)

Comment: That is exactly what was happening. Thank you so much, I'm new with Jenkins hahaha.
I really thought git was a directory, I'll do some research about how it works on linux.

Comment: If this answer is helpful for you, please consider to mark it as answer so that community can benefit from it.